# Needing Help Utilizing Linq with lists vb net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am creating a routine that opens a SQL reader and loads a "Strapping Chart" (this will look up a predefined number that correlates to a specific volume of a vessel).  On form load I want to populate the list these numbers will not change.  (VolCnt , Volume).  I am wanting to retrieve the correlated Volume based on the volumecount.
Here is what I have :

```
Public HltVolVals As List(Of HLTVolValChart)

Public Class HLTVolValChart
    Public Property VCnt As Double
    Public Property Volume As Double
    Public Sub New(ByVal n_Vcnt As Double, ByVal n_Volume As Double)
        Vcnt = n_Vcnt
        Volume = n_Volume
    End Sub
End Class


Public Sub PopulateHLTVolVals()
    Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT VCnt, Volume FROM Vol_Strap WHERE Vessel = 'HLT' ORDER BY Volume"
    Dim CN As New SqlConnection
    Dim Reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim SQL As New SqlCommand

    CN.ConnectionString = Connectionstr
    CN.Open()
    SQL.Connection = CN
    SQL.CommandText = sqlstr
    Reader = SQL.ExecuteReader
    While Reader.Read
        Dim Vol As Double = CDbl(Reader.GetValue(1))
        Dim VCnt As Double = CDbl(Reader.GetValue(0))
        Dim NewHLTVolValChartItem As List(Of HLTVolValChart) = New List(Of HLTVolValChart)
        NewHLTVolValChartItem.Add(New HLTVolValChart(VCnt, Vol))
    End While
    Reader.Close()

    CN.Close()
    CN.Dispose()

End Sub

Public Function ListHLTVals(ByVal CurCnt As Double) As Double

    Dim QVol = From _HLTVol In HltVolVals
           Where _HLTVol.VCnt >= CurCnt
           Select _HLTVol.Volume Take 1

    Return QVol.First
End Function
```

The problem that I am having (I think) is while I loop through the records I am not creating multiple values within HLTVolValChart. However, I am not sure of the proper way to accomplish this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your loop don't re-initialize the `NewHLTVolValChartItem` variable. That make a new List every iteration - just remove that.

Comment: What's the purpose of `NewHLTVolValChartItem`.  Don't you want to use `HltVolVals`?

Answer (score 0):

Make `NewHLTVolValChartItem` a class variable. In your loop don't re-initialize the `NewHLTVolValChartItem` variable. That make a new List every iteration - just remove that part.

```
Private NewHLTVolValChartItem As New List(Of HLTVolValChart)

Public Sub PopulateHLTVolVals()
 Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT VCnt, Volume FROM Vol_Strap WHERE Vessel = 'HLT' ORDER BY Volume"
 Dim CN As New SqlConnection
 Dim Reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
 Dim SQL As New SqlCommand

 CN.ConnectionString = Connectionstr
 CN.Open()
 SQL.Connection = CN
 SQL.CommandText = sqlstr
 Reader = SQL.ExecuteReader
 While Reader.Read
   Dim Vol As Double = CDbl(Reader.GetValue(1))
   Dim VCnt As Double = CDbl(Reader.GetValue(0))
   NewHLTVolValChartItem.Add(New HLTVolValChart(VCnt, Vol))
 End While
 Reader.Close()

 CN.Close()
 CN.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I just was overlooking the "New"

Comment: Public HltVolVals As New List(Of HLTVolValChart)